# failure to start batch file, not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've got this 1 line of code in a batch file that is suppose to start another batch file but keep moving on with the rest of the script, basically making a workflow program.

```
start "" "files/network/connectWifi.bat"
```

This returns as `'files' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`, which doesn't make sense to me as the path is inside of quotes.

What could be causing this? How can I solve the issue?

The path works when using `call "files/network/connectWifi.bat"`, but I would rather use `start` so that the rest of the script can continue to run.

Comment: Does it work if you use backslashes?  Forward slashes are not normal on Microsoft platforms except for web addresses.  To my internal command line parser, you are trying to run the program named "files" with an argument of /network/connectWifi.bat.

Comment: That did solve the issue. Weird that the forward slashes work elsewhere. Could you write an answer @hoodaticus

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, in my experience with most of microsoft's console utilities, it works maybe 20% of the time.  I remember testing this theory many years ago but can't recall which commands did and did not work.